# SSH "Write failed / Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, ssh

When I try to connect to my SSH server (running Arch Linux) at home from my school (on my Windows 8 laptop), I sometimes get "Write failed: Connection reset by peer," and other times "Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer." I can't post the error right now because I'm not at school and it only happens while at school, but I believe the last line before either of the above is "SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent." This ONLY happens at school - I am able to connect over my mobile hotspot.

So far, I have tried:

1. Changing Use_DNS to 'no' in sshd_config
2. Reinstalling ssh_server
3. Changing to port 443 to avoid blocked ports
4. Changing the Cipher list
5. Generating new keys (on server)

Again, this only happens at school. Because of this, I assume it's because they are blocking ports. However, I tried it on port 443 and it didn't work, and I will be trying port 80 later today (as much as I don't want to open port 80).

Thanks for taking time to help me if you so choose, I'm new to SSH and have little experience with anything in networking.

UPDATE: Port 80 works. Odd that port 443 was blocked...

Comment: Does the connection work and then suddenly break with one of those errors? Or does it never get established in the first place?

Comment: It connects, but breaks before authentication - however, the problem was figured out, the school has blocked port 443. Port 80 is available. Not really on topic (and is very much a newbie question), but is it safe to have port 80 forwarded at home?

Comment: Possible answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157556/rsync-connection-reset-by-peer. This is the most useful I found.