# How to fix SSH error "Write failed: Connection reset by peer" on server side?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I was running a long SSH process remotely on an Ubuntu machine (16.04) for a few hours, and eventually I got:

```
Write failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I was wondering what the cause is. Is it a time out error because it's taking too long? As the error suggests, it seems that the problem lies with the server and the server is initiating this.

My question is that is there something I can do on `openssh-server` to fix this problem, e.g. by increasing certain time limits?

By the way, I am using the ssh client coming from MinGW/MSYS. I am now trying repeating the process using a different SSH client to see if this is a random issue with the network or is it a server configuration problem.

Comment: 1) try to change TCPKeepAlive 2) if server host is "far" (not in same LAN),  from client host, try pinging the other to maintain connection pen.

Comment: Possible solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157556/rsync-connection-reset-by-peer This is the most useful I found.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://superuser.com/questions/886822/ssh-write-failed-read-from-socket-failed-connection-reset-by-peer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a client issue, not a server-side one.

I switched to specialized SSH clients such as the BitVise SSH client, and never had this issue again.